# Creating PDF with iText based on a list of HTML strings

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to create a large PDF file from a bunch of HTML strings. Each is a separate document - so it's not a new paragraph or smth like that. It works when I concatenate all pages (HTML strings) into one and call createPdf. However, in some cases, it takes a lot of memory so I've tried creating it without a need of concatenating HTML into one. I've noticed there's a param named finish - for the createPdf method. When it's set to false it looks like it's not closing the out put stream allowing me to render more pages. I've tried to call createPdf(HTML, finish=true) at the end of the processing. However, it renders just the final page :(
Am I doing anything wrong or the way of doing that is just not possible and the finish param purpose is different than I thought.
pseudo-code of what I'm doing now:

```
loop - start
string = grab HTML
renderer.setDocumentFromString(string)
renderer.create(outputStream, finish = false)
loop - end
renderer.setDocumentFromString("<html/>")
renderer.create(outputStream, finish = true)
```

Comment: Hi, can you attach your actual code that reproduces the problem? Have you tried iText 7?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use that version due to licensing reasons :( I'll post more code shortly.